# User interface for generating Phing build files?

Tags: php, integration, phing, continuous

I want to use [Phing](http://www.phing.info/trac/) as a build tool and I was wondering if there any (web) interface  for generating build files.

Any recommendations on alternative methods to writing those by hand would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of GUI editors for ANT build files, which is what Phing is based on.

A quick google found this.
http://antsnest.sourceforge.net/

IDE's such as eclipse also have plugins for editing ant buildfiles, and should be fairly workable with phing.

None of these are web based though, sorry.